# How to handle Email on Google TV

Tags: google-tv

My HoneyComb application runs on tablets and Google TV.  I have setting to send email in my settings fragment, but it returns error of "No app can handle this function."

Is there a way to send email to browser through my application if there is no client (createChooser) available?

I also tried to display a summary of the customer service email, but summary is not working on HoneyComb.  I was trying this so I could have disabled Intent on tv.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to send email to browser through my application if there is no client (createChooser) available?

Not unless you know the specific email Web app and all of its details, and that email Web app supports some sort of direct-email-sending capability.

Either prompt the user to install an email app, or send the email yourself (e.g., JavaMail), or do not use email for communications on Google TV. I would expect few Google TV users to be using email on their televisions, so you need to plan accordingly.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Google TV includes a default, stub email app, so the system will *appear* to have an email app installed, even when there is none.  There's a special check necessary to detect the stub:

```
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");  // special mime legacy for gmail; others work
        List<ResolveInfo> match = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
        boolean hasEmailer = match.size() > 0;
        Log.w("thuuz", "has plain/text Emailer: " + hasEmailer);

        if (match.size() == 1) {
            ResolveInfo info = match.get(0);
            boolean real = true;
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.startsWith("com.google.android.tv.frameworkpackagestubs"))
                real = false;
            Log.w("thuuz", "has *real* Emailer: " + real);
        }
```